# How can I find the percentage of numbers in a list that meet some criteria?

Tags: python

I have a list of 10000 random numbers from 1 to 100.
I need to know the percentage of numbers that are less than 40 and the percentage of numbers that are more than 60, how I can do that?

Comment: Count them and divide by 10000?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking and there also seems to be no effort on your part to solve this. Please clarify and show that you tried something on your own.

Comment: the qustion is how I can count them :(

Comment: I found it - thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'd use list comprehensions to find the appropriate elements, and then just divide the lengths of the output list from the original:

```
origLen = float(len(mylist)) # float used to avoid integer division
interestingLen = len([i for i in mylist if i < 40 or i > 60])
under40Percent = interestingLen/origLen
```

Comment: So to generalise this, define yourself a function that replaces `40` in @Mureinik's answer with whatever value you input.

Answer (score 0):

thank you
that work

```
for i in lijst:
    if i >=60 :
        groter60.append(i)
    elif i <=40:
        kleiner40.append(i)
    else:
        ander.append(i)

x=(len(kleiner40)+len(kleiner40)) /( len(lijst))*100
print "het percentage van minder dan 40 en groter dan 60 is %.5f procent" % (x)
```